# Google distance matrix web service limit

Tags: android, iphone, ios, google-maps

According to this [Google document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#Limits) there are limits on using `Distance matrix` web service.

From the document :

```
Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of information on a
Google Map.Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a Google map
is prohibited.
```

I am not clear whether I meet this limit or not.

Let me explain how I use this web service. I call this api from server to get distance between locations. Using this distance I just decide that `user1`'s entered location is near to `user2`'s entered location or not. I don't use this information to display on google map. But at client side I display google maps with marker for user's entered location and markers for nearby users' location.

Using web service and google maps this way, do I satisfy the above mentioned limit?

**Note :** I also call direction web service at client-side to display routes on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MAPS API**

Your usage is fine. I think the whole point of the Google guidelines you quoted above are to stop people using the distance matrix and other Google Maps APIs (without a Google MAPS API business account) from using it outside of any "app" scope for financial gain or in situations where there is a simpler solution that doesn't require their API. (I will get to this soon)

This is also the reason they impose lower limits on the numbers of API calls you can make per day when using a free Google Maps key:

*Normal   - 2 500 elements per 24 hour period.*

*Business - 100 000 elements per 24 hour period.*

I've used many of the Google maps API services on free accounts across a broad range of applications, some that match the scenario you have state above, others that do not. We have never had a problem at all and as long as people use the API fairly, they shouldn't either.

---

**Other ways**

There are other ways of doing what you require. You could calculate the distance between the two locations using the Haversine Foruma

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

and then send this distance down to your app upon request. This would remove the need for the Distance Matrix API in some circumstances (I'm unsure how indepth your App and Web Services actually are).

Comment: I need to get driving distance. I am only worried that my usage of web service should match their terms and conditions.

Comment: @Akash as long as you're not abusing the MAPS API, you'll be fine. If you're using the data constructively and using the results in some form or another, direct or indirect in your app (as you stated you were) you will have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead use straight line distance between two points?

Try to find something similar to Android's [Location.distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5b%5d%29) in the language you use for your server or just port the code from Android.

Comment: I need driving distance.